# Find last cell with values using indexes

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop, vba

I try to find the last cell in a column that contains values. I know I can use something like:

```
Dim findme As Range = excel.Range("A1:A" & lastrow.row)
```

but I am looking for a way not to use this column-character format. Something like this VBA format

```
Dim rng as range
with myWorksheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rng = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))
end with
```

Comment: That is the way to do it. Bare in mind that if `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)` has a value you will not get the last used cell when using the `End` function.

Comment: Still strange, I always thought: "If I can do it in VBA I can do it in VB.NET via Interop too". Apparentely this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an helper class to solve this problem:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class FindLastCellByIndex
    Private Shared Function getStringRangeFormat(ByVal colNumber As Long, ByVal rowNumber As Long) As String
        If colNumber > 0 AndAlso colNumber < 27 Then
            Dim c As Char
            c = Convert.ToChar(colNumber + 64)
            Return (c & rowNumber & ":" & c).ToString
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function getSearchRange(ByRef _sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal Col As Long, ByVal startRow As Long) As Excel.Range
        Dim strColCharSpez As String = getStringRangeFormat(Col, startRow)
       'Build String
        Dim rng As Excel.Range = DirectCast(_sheet.Cells(_sheet.Rows.Count, startRow), Excel.Range)
        Dim t As Long
        t = rng.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row

        Return _sheet.Range(strColCharSpez & t)

    End Function
End Class
```

This is the way to use it:

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range = FindLastCellByIndex.getSearchRange(_sheet, 3, 3)
```

Now you get the Range: `Range(Cells(3,3)`, `Cells(LastRow, 3)` as an object.