# Determining the last cell in a specific range and filling it, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I need to determine the first empty cell in each of the ranges "Revision Level" ("C82:F91"), "Date of Revision" ("G82:G91"), and "Comments or Notes for Revision"("H82:R91"), and fill it with the correct information. For "revlvl" I need it to just add one to the previous value, the other information I know how to calculate.

So what it needs to do here is on the line down from the 000 rev level it would put 001 in Revision level, todays date in  Date of revision, and the text input into the inputbox into comments and notes. Then if the loop is ran again it would put in 003, date, and notes in the 3rd line down.

There are other references in the loop because it is comparing dates in two charts above, they work properly and dont need to be changed. The parts in question are highlighted, currently the locations are hard coded.

[image: This is the sheet im working with and the ranges]

[image]

```
If Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("G82") = "" Then
'do nothing
Else

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Revnotes As Range
    Dim RevDate As Range
    Dim revlvl As Range

    Set Revnotes = Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("H83:R83")
    Set RevDate = Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("G83")
    Set revlvl = Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("C83:F91")

    For i = 0 To 49

    cRow = i + 23

        For j = 0 To 2

                If Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 11) <> Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 37) Then
                    RevDate = Date
                    Revnotes = InputBox("You Changed dates, you must imput notes for this revison!", "Notes")
                    revlvl = Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("C83") + 1

                        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                        Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("K23:M72").Copy
                        Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("AK23:AM72").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                    End
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

    End If
```

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) You might benefit from reading [ask].

Comment: A quick search on here, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27225857/4961700  not saying it is the "perfect" answer, but should help...

Comment: Added code, I also have been searching for a while but wasn't able to get anything to work, hence why im asking.

Comment: In addition to that im very new to this and do not understand very well what is going on in the thread linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the next free row in range `C82:F91` use something like the follwing so you don't need to loop.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Monthly Status").Range("C82:F91")

Dim NextFreeRow As Long
With rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1)
    If .Value = vbNullString Then 'test if range is full
        NextFreeRow = .End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find next free row
    Else
        MsgBox "range is full"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'add +1 to the previous value
Worksheets("Monthly Status").Cells(NextFreeRow, "C").Value = Worksheets("Monthly Status").Cells(NextFreeRow - 1, "C").Value + 1
```

This example should help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and solved my issue.